# How to improve the lag-effect of my Shiny-App

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I have below `Shiny-App`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
    column(3,
           div(id = "01", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", HTML("01")),
           div(id = "02", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: blue", HTML("02")),
           div(id = "03", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: red", HTML("03")),
    )

)



server = function(input, output,session) { 
    Plot_I = reactiveValues()
        Get_1 =
          function(Plot_I) {
                Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_1"
            }
        Get_2 =
          function(Plot_I) {
                Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_2"
            }
        Get_3 =
          function(Plot_I) {
                Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_3"
            }

      observe({
      onclick('01', 
            {Get_1(Plot_I)
            showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                            column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
                        )
                )

            }
            )
          })

      observe({
      onclick('02', 
            {Get_2(Plot_I)
            showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                            column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
                        )
                )

            }
            )
          })

      observe({
      onclick('03', 
            {Get_3(Plot_I)
            showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                            column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
                        )
                )

            }
            )
          })


        output$Indiv_Plot_All_Title = 
        renderText({
          req(Plot_I$x)

          if (Plot_I$x == "Plot_Get_1") {
              "Plot 1"
            } else if (Plot_I$x == "Plot_Get_2") {
              "Plot 2"
            } else {
              "Plot 3"
            }
        })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The goal is when user click on a specific Div, different value will be displayed in the `modal-dialog` box.

However while this is working as intended, in this approach, I still see some kind of lag effect. For example, when user click first `div` and then the second `div`, I see the value for the first `div` is still visible for some moment in the `modal-dialog`.

Is there any way to remove this lag?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your server code:

```
outputOptions(output, "Indiv_Plot_All_Title", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Your code will become:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
  column(3,
         div(id = "01", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", HTML("01")),
         div(id = "02", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: blue", HTML("02")),
         div(id = "03", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: red", HTML("03")),
  )

)



server = function(input, output,session) { 
  Plot_I = reactiveValues()
  Get_1 =
    function(Plot_I) {
      Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_1"
    }
  Get_2 =
    function(Plot_I) {
      Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_2"
    }
  Get_3 =
    function(Plot_I) {
      Plot_I$x = "Plot_Get_3"
    }

  observe({
    onclick('01', 
            {Get_1(Plot_I)
              showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                                    column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
              )
              )

            }
    )
  })

  observe({
    onclick('02', 
            {Get_2(Plot_I)
              showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                                    column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
              )
              )

            }
    )
  })

  observe({
    onclick('03', 
            {Get_3(Plot_I)
              showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE,
                                    column(9, htmlOutput("Indiv_Plot_All_Title"))
              )
              )

            }
    )
  })


  output$Indiv_Plot_All_Title = 
    renderText({
      req(Plot_I$x)

      if (Plot_I$x == "Plot_Get_1") {
        "Plot 1"
      } else if (Plot_I$x == "Plot_Get_2") {
        "Plot 2"
      } else {
        "Plot 3"
      }
    })

  outputOptions(output, "Indiv_Plot_All_Title", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The lag is due to the contents of `modalDialog()` only being updated *after* it is opened. By setting `suspendWhenHidden` in `outputOptions()` to `FALSE`, you are forcing Shiny to update everytime there is a change (i.e. everytime `output$Indiv_Plot_All_Title` is changed), even if `modalDialog()` hasn't been called and opened yet.